# select result set row to columns transformation

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I've a table `remarks` with columns `id, story_id, like` like can be `+1`, `-1` 
I want my `select` query to return the following columns `story_id, total, n_like, n_dislike` where `total = n_like + n_dislike` without sub queries.

I am currently doing a `group by` on `like` and `select`ing  `like as like_t, count(like) as total` which is giving me an output like

```
-- like_t --+ --- total --
    -1      |      2
     1      |      6
```

and returning two rows in result set. But what I want is to get `1` row where `n_like is 6` and n_dislike is `2` and `total` is `8`

Answer (score 1):

First, `LIKE` is a reserved word in PostgreSQL, so you have to double-quote it. Maybe a better name should be picked for this column.

```sql
CREATE TABLE testbed (id int4, story_id int4, "like" int2);
INSERT INTO testbed VALUES
    (1,1,'+1'),(1,1,'+1'),(1,1,'+1'),
    (1,1,'+1'),(1,1,'+1'),(1,1,'+1'),
    (1,1,'-1'),(1,1,'-1');

SELECT
    story_id,
    sum(CASE WHEN "like" > 0 THEN abs("like") ELSE 0 END) AS n_like,
    sum(CASE WHEN "like" < 0 THEN abs("like") ELSE 0 END) AS n_dislike,
    count(story_id) AS total
    -- for cases +2 / -3 in the "like" field, use following construct instead
    -- sum(abs("like")) AS total
  FROM testbed
 GROUP BY story_id;
```

I used `abs("like")` for cases when you'll have `+2` or `-3` in your `"like"` column.

Comment: Yes the real column name is not like, But the problem is these `+1`, `-1` are not integers, they are some `enum` type. so `abs` and sum will not work. only `count` will.so just (CASE WHEN "like" > 0 THEN count("like") ELSE 0 END) AS n_like works . Thanks

Comment: Better use `CASE WHEN "like" > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` for the n_like field. Also, maybe it's better to make values numeric?

Comment: If `+1` and `-1` are the only possibilities should I assign the whole `numeric` set to it ? The query is giving two rows one for `+like`  where `n_like = n` and `n_dislike = 0` and another row for `dislikes` where `n_like = 0` and `n_dislike = n`,  But I want it in one row

Comment: Something wrong here. I just tested this query, it gives only one row per story_id. It is not possible to get more due to `GROUP BY story_id`, unless you have modified the initial query.